# react native vison camera Cannot convert value of type '[AnyHashable : Any]' to expected argument type '[String : Any]'

Tags: react-native

/Users/firozahmed/Desktop/MyApp/node_modules/react-native-vision-camera/ios/CameraView+RecordVideo.swift:135:70: Cannot convert value of type '[AnyHashable : Any]' to expected argument type '[String : Any]'

I am stuck at the above build error. I am using XCode 12.4 & react-native: 0.66.4

Comment: This type of error usually comes from the wrong prop being passed in somewhere. Make sure you're not passing an object to the component where it's expecting a string. It also helps if you post your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After researching a lot, i've found out (see reference below) that the last version of RNVC that works with iOS (until XCode 12) it v2.10.0.

Reference:
[Build Failed in new app created with react-native init #716](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/issues/716#issuecomment-1070615380)

Answer (score -2):

i faced with this issue too
i think it is a bug and for fix this:
1: remove module folder from node_modules
2: npm i react-native-vision-camera@2.9.4
3: npx pod-install

i test this version and its worked